# adminCenter deploy Web Sphere Liberty

Tags: docker, websphere, websphere-liberty

Is it possible to enable the "Deploy" option on a standalone Web Sphere Liberty Server running into a docker container using the official images? When i login to adminCenter i just can see this options:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The deploy option is only available when using a collective. We don't recommend using collectives when running in docker, instead we recommend using a docker management system like kubernetes to distribute docker containers.